# Преобразование char в string

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Как приравнять значение перенной str типа NSString значению переменной ch типа char?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`char` --> `NSString *`**

```
char sym = 'q';  
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c", sym];
```

---

**`const char *` / `char *` -->**

```
const char *cstr = "Some string";
NSString *object = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: cstr];
NSString *pbject = [NSString stringWithCString: cstr encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

---

**NSString * --> const char** *

```
NSString* string = @"NSString" ;
const char *cstr = [string cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
const char *cstr2 = [string UTF8String] ;
```

---

**NSString * --> char[]**

```
NSString* string = @"NSString" ;
char buffer[kBufferSize];
if (![string getCString: &buffer maxLength: kBufferSize encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]) {
    // buffer is too small
} else {
    // buffer = "NSString";
}
```

---

[NSString Class Reference](http://bit.ly/J625R1)

> [+ stringWithCString:encoding:](http://bit.ly/OE4RgR)
> [+ stringWithUTF8String:](http://bit.ly/PcY9mE)
> [– cStringUsingEncoding:](http://bit.ly/Nven7f)
> [– getCString:maxLength:encoding:](http://bit.ly/NtBnGG)
> [– UTF8String](http://bit.ly/PcYeXx)

Comment: Какой развернутый ответ!